How to redirect domain to subfolder based on url path?
I have an application developed by reactjs and php laravel.
I want to deploy deploy this in a shared hosting with each subfolders not  submitted domain.
Example Folder Structure:
ReactApp -> /ReactApp/
Laravel -> /Laravel/
Now,
If I open www.example.com it should be directed to /ReactApp/ folder
If I open www.example.com/api/ it should be redirected to /Laravel/ folder.
How can I achieve this using htaccess.
I don't want to use subdomain here since I don't have SSL for subdomains.

Do you already have a .htaccess inside /ReactApp/ and /Laravel subdirectories?

Redirecting a domain to a subfolder based on the URL path can be done using server-side configuration files such as .htaccess for Apache servers, or using server configurations for Nginx servers.

Do you know commands for the redirect. I'm looking for it.
